How do you type in characters like []{} etc. without looking on the keyboard? (QWERTZ-Layout)
This is probably only an issue in the German community. I've switched to Linux now and after some hours of research I did not find any pleasing solution for this. To type in e.g. '{', I have to press AltGr + 7, which is impossible for me to do without looking on the keyboard. I am used to press Ctrl + Alt + 7 on Windows. How do you handle this? Does anyone know a solution for this?
I am using Ubuntu 24.04.1
